# function to check whether an element is present in the page

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Created a function to check whether an element is present on a page or not. Intention is to wait for a specified period of time and then return false, if not present.

public boolean isElementPresent(final WebElement element) {

```
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    return wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            return element.isDisplayed() != false;
        }
    });
}
```

But this is throwing exception in case of element not found

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do accept the answer if you find them useful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is throwing exception because findElement will throw exception if no element is found. It is used in isDisplayed() method. You can 1st check, whether element is present on page then check whether it is displayed. Use following to make 1st check.

```
driver.findElements(byLocator).size>0
```

Comment: Thanks Husam, for the feedback. But i did not get the purpose of size here. how it will solve my purpose. Moreover, i do have getsize() function available but not size().

Comment: findElements(), method does not throw an exception if no such element exists on page and it returns a list of all matching elements found. So if the size of list returned is > 0, it means your element is present on page. After this you can check whether that element is displayed on page or not. This way you will not get the exception you were getting earlier. size() is method of java List class. Make correct import : import java.util.List;

Answer (score 0):

The following is a crude solution. But it works nevertheless :p

```
public boolean isElementPresent() {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocatedBy(By.id(""));
        return true;  
    } catch (TimeOutException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When we use the WebDriverWait Class for waiting for a element to be present in the web page, a TimeOut Exception is thrown after the specified time. We catch it and return false. If no exception is thrown(if element is found), we return true.

If you are looking for checking whether the  element is enabled or is displayed, explore the isDisplayed or isEnabled methods associated with WebElement. But please note that if the element is not physically present in the webpage, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any further clarifications.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but i think returning something from the catch block is not a good coding practice.. Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Like I said in the beginning, the method is crude. Hasam's code will work fine for you then. Please check the new method I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another less 'barbaric' method :-

```
public boolean isElementPresent() {  
    List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementsLocatedBy(By.id(""));
    if (elements.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
 public boolean fncCheckElement() {
try {
    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver,1)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.id("ID"))));
 system.out.println("Element is present in web page")  
 return true;  
} catch (Throwable e) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    system.out.println("Element is not present  in web page")
    return false;
}}
```

Enjoy!