# Selenium Webdriver: best practice to handle a NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

After much searching and reading, I'm still unclear as to the best way to handle a failed assertion using Webdriver.  I would have thought this was a common and core piece of functionality. All I want to do is:

- look for an element
- if present - tell me
- if not present - tell me

I want to present the results for a non technical audience, so having it throw 'NoSuchElementExceptions' with a full stack trace is not helpful.  I simply want a nice message.

My test:

```
@Test
public void isMyElementPresent(){
  //  WebElement myElement driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myElement"));
    if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myElement"))!=null){
        System.out.println("My element was found on the page");
    }else{
            System.out.println("My Element was not found on the page");
        }
    }
```

I still get a NoSuchElementException thrown when I force a fail.  Do I need a try/catch as well?  Can I incorporate Junit assertions and/or Hamcrest to generate a more meaningful message without the need for a System.out.println?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have encountered similar situations. According to the [Javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) for the `findElement` and `findElements` APIs, it appears that the `findElement` behavior is by design. You should use `findElements` to check for non-present elements.

Since in your case, there's a chance that the WebElement is not present, you should use `findElements` instead.

I'd use this as follows.

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#myElement"));
if (elems.size == 0) {
        System.out.println("My element was not found on the page");
} else
        System.out.println("My element was found on the page");
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, when run within a @Test method, it provides a 'Pass' in Junit results even when it the element is not found, so gives a false positive in the exported XML / HTML results.

Comment: @Steerpike, then fail (i.e google "fail JUnit test" ) the test if the first condition is true. This answer was merely to show you the basic principle.

Comment: OK - thanks, I can't beleive I've not come across the fail(string) method until now!

Answer (score 2):

you can do something to check if element exists

```
  public boolean isElementExists(By by) {
    boolean isExists = true;
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        isExists = false;
    }
    return isExists;
}
```

Comment: Is it ideal to use try catch block in this way ? I think @vish's way is better.

Comment: @lost: `findElements` will try to find *all elements* on page. So if it founds first and only element still it will parse rest of the page to check if there are more matching elements. It gives a little overhead

Comment: Your code works for sure !! But I believe the try catch blocks are not meant to be used in this manner. Again it is my opinion.

Comment: @lost: Instead of manners and believes I prefer performance. Its my opinion.

Comment: @lost: Also in OPs case maximum number of desired element is 1 so I will prefer `findElement`

Comment: Funnily enough I never thought of this solution when I encountered this issue :) Good alternative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511901/function-to-check-whether-an-element-is-present-in-the-page/21557246#21557246

Comment: @lost: Your solution is also good. I dont see any issue in returning from catch.

Comment: They are both good suggestions - thank you. I am running this test against >500 pages so performance is a concern.  How about I try both methods and report back on the most performant?

Answer (score 1):

What about using an xPath inside of a try-catch, passing the elementype, attribute and text as follows?

```
try {
    driver.FindElement(
        By.XPath(string.Format("//{0}[contains(@{1}, '{2}')]", 
        strElemType, strAttribute, strText)));
    return true;
}
catch (Exception) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even running it in a try block, it behaves as if unhandled,
neither of the catch blocks runs when the selenium exception occurs.

```java
try {
    wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.PageSource.Contains(waitforTitle));
    wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(waitforControlName)).Displayed);
}
catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException nse) {
    nse = nse = null;
    success = false;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex = ex = null;
    success = false;
}
```