# Can isDisplayed() return false without breaking run in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to use conditional function using .isDisplayed() method. Everything is working correct as long as this method returns true.

HTML is not required I think here, because I have only one button to be visible on the page, which is correclty found (I successfully clicked the button with the following `xpath`.

Now I try with:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='button1']")).isDisplayed()) {
     //do stuff
}
else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

Or even

```
WebElement withdrawnBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='button1']"));
boolean isVisible = withdrawnBtn.isDisplayed();
if (isVisible) {
     //do stuff
}
else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

but both conditionals fails, if in the first run there should be executed code from `else`, because everytime when the button is not available, there is fail pointing on the line with `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='button1']")).isDisplayed());` - fails, because the button is not displayed. I need t o do something, when the button is not displayed instead failing code...

Comment: Check out HTML standard. Any element in DOM can be (if I am to simplify): displayed (usually the most obvious and common kind), missing (there's no such element anywhere), hidden (by numerous methods, including setting a `visibility:none`). You will have to rethink your code around that, usually quick answers are incorrect ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before checking isDisplayed conditions we need to check whether element exist on the page or not Otherwise it will throw Nosuchelementfound exception

driver.findElements("Locator").size()-- will return integer value if the element exist on the page.

Below is the fix code.

```
  int size = driver.findElements("Locator").size();
    if(size!=0){
         if(driver.findElement("Locator").isDisplayed()){
             // do operations
         }
    }
```

After reading comments, I got to know isEmpty is better way to use instead of size I made changes to the above code.

```
WebDriver driver;
List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("test"));
if(!webElements.isEmpty()){
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("test")).isDisplayed()){
        // do operations
    }
 }
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: You should avoid using `Collection::size()` if the only thing you're interested in is `Collection::isEmpty()`. Certain types of collections required to go a long mile to compute their sizes, usually a lot more than to say if they are empty or not.

Comment: isEmpty looks better - int takes more space all in all comparing to boolean :)

Comment: Thanks @M. Prokhorov, I updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use following to identify if an element exists or not:

```
private boolean isPresent(WebElement element) {
try {
    element;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was thinking about catching NoElementFound exception, but I found this issue:
[Selenium Webdriver: best practice to handle a NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780964/selenium-webdriver-best-practice-to-handle-a-nosuchelementexception)

using link above I used:

```
List<WebElement> withdrawnBtn = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@id='button1']"));
if (withdrawnBtn.size() != 0) {
     //do stuff
}
else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Michal my first solution is also same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of size() method you could use isEmpty() method.